# convert JQuery code to Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to rewrite the following JQuery to Pure Javascript.

I don't know why the code isn't working, but it isn't working. I'm guessing I'm doing wrong with the use of "focusing". Would anybody help me please?

JQuery(working)

```
$('.form-group input').on('focus blur', function (e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('active', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
}).trigger('blur');
```

This is what I have so far(not working).

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group input")
Array.from(inputs).forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("focusin", (e) => {
    const t = e.target as HTMLInputElement
    let formgroup = t.parentElement
    if(t.value.length > 0 ){
      formgroup.classList.toggle("onblur")
    }
  })
})
```

Here is the html tag.

```
    <form action="#" id="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label-control">
            <span class="label-text">Email</span>
          </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label-control">
            <span class="label-text">Password</span>
          </label> 
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn" />
    </form>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Or what is the console saying?

Comment: Hi, I don't get any error from the dev tool console. So it probably running but I'm misunderstanding some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues in regards to the jQuery code.

The class is named `active` and you are using `onblur`. The jquery code runs on both focus and blur.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group input");
const focusBlurHandler = (e) => {
    const t = e.target;
    let formgroup = t.parentElement;
    if(t.value.length > 0 ){
      formgroup.classList.toggle("active");
    }
};

Array.from(inputs).forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("focusin", focusBlurHandler);
  input.addEventListener("focusout", focusBlurHandler);
});
```

```css
.active{background:lightgreen}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label-control">
            <span class="label-text">Email</span>
          </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label-control">
            <span class="label-text">Password</span>
          </label> 
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day. I edited my code based on the suggestion and it working great now. Thank you!